# How can I make ISPconfig 3 use SSL?

Tags: apache, ssl, https, webserver, vhosts

I've been trying to get ISPconfig 3 to accept my ssl certificates, and it seems to go fine, except that it doesn't change the vhost-files to enable ssl, even when ticking the 'SSL' box in ISPconfig. The certificate supplier only has a guide for ISPconfig 2, which is not compatible with 3. I have tried several things, but as I don't have any experience with both SSL and vhosts, I didn't get very far.
I have 2 SSL certificates, for 2 sites, running on the same server. Atm I have the certificate of one of the sites in the 'SSL Certificate' box at ISPconfig, and have 'SSLCACertificateFile /var/www/{myDomain}/ssl/InstantSSL_Bundle.crt' in both ISPconfig's 'Apache directives' and in /etc/httpd.conf (which is empty except for the line I added).

- OS: Debian Lenny
- Webserver: Apache2
- ISPconfig: 3.0.3.3